# Population of randomly dividing cell

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics

I was really curious. What if, instead of dividing into two every day, the cell divides into one, two, or three, and the probability of all three cases is $1/3$. Initially, there's one. After n days, what is the average number of cell?

Comment: To me, the result is not surprising. However, this is an interesting question.

Comment: How did you get roughly $2\cdot 3^{n-1}$ rather than $2^n$?

Comment: It is possible to find the probability distribution using generating functions: start with $x$ and then replace $x$ by $\frac13(x+x^2+x^3)$ then do this replacement again and again and again.  Expand and tidy up to get, for $n=4$ something like $\frac1{81}x+\frac{40}{2187}x^2 + \frac{1600}{59049}x^3 $ $+ \cdots$ $+ \frac{14}{450283905890997363}x^{79}$ $+ \frac{1}{450283905890997363}x^{80}  $ $+\frac{1}{12157665459056928801}x^{81}$ with the coefficient of $x^k$ indicating the probability of $k$ bacteria on day $n=4$

Comment: Thank you so much. I found an error in the code I programmed, and it looks like it should come out as a power of two, as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_0=1$ and, for each $k\geq 1$, take $X_k$ as the number of bacteria on the $k^{\text{th}}$ day.

If $U_1,U_2,U_3\dots$ is a sequece of $\text{iid}$ random variables that possess a discrete uniform distribution on the set $\{1,2,3\}$, then we may express $X_k$ as a random sum: $$X_k=U_1 +\dots+U_{X_{k-1}}$$

From total law of expectation, $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{E}(X_k) &=& \mathbb{E}\Big(\mathbb{E}(X_k|X_{k-1})\Big) \\ &=& \mathbb{E}\Bigg(\mathbb{E}\Big(U_1 +\dots +U_{X_{k-1}}\Big|X_{k-1}\Big)\Bigg) \\ &=& \mathbb{E}\Big(\mathbb{E}(U_1|X_{k-1})+\dots +\mathbb{E}(U_{X_{k-1}}|X_{k-1})\Big) \\ &=& \mathbb{E}(2X_{k-1}) \\ &=& 2\mathbb{E}(X_{k-1})\\ \end{eqnarray*}$$ Since $\mathbb{E}(X_1)$ clearly equals $2$ we see with recursion that $\mathbb{E}(X_k)=2^k$ for any $k\geq 1$.